# Zoomed background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a problem on my website qubik-design.co.nf when i am on 'Contact' or 'Quienes somos', etc my background image is zoomed an it fits the height entirely and i would like it to appear as the homepage background. Deactivating the supersized tag the background shows properly but it produces an error and infinite scroll appears.

```
<ul id="supersized" class="quality" style="visibility: visible;">
    <li class="slide-0 activeslide">
        <a target="_blank">
            <img src="http://qubik-design.co.nf/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/intro-bg1.jpg" style="width: 1903px; top: -469.5px; left: 0px; height: 1427.25px;">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The supersized.css:

```
#supersized-loader { position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; z-index:0; width:60px; height:60px; margin:-30px 0 0 -30px; text-indent:-999em; background:url(../images/img/progress.gif) no-repeat center center;}

    #supersized {  display:block; position:fixed; left:0; top:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:-999; height:100%; width:100%; }
        #supersized img { width:auto; height:auto; position:relative; display:none; outline:none; border:none; }
            #supersized.speed img { -ms-interpolation-mode:nearest-neighbor; image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges; }   /*Speed*/
            #supersized.quality img { -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; image-rendering: optimizeQuality; }           /*Quality*/

        #supersized li { display:block; list-style:none; z-index:-30; position:fixed; overflow:hidden; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:#111; }
        #supersized a { width:100%; height:100%; display:block; }
            #supersized li.prevslide { z-index:-20; }
            #supersized li.activeslide { z-index:-10; }
            #supersized li.image-loading { background:#111 url(../images/img/progress.gif) no-repeat center center; width:100%; height:100%; }
                #supersized li.image-loading img{ visibility:hidden; }
            #supersized li.prevslide img, #supersized li.activeslide img{ display:inline; max-width:none; }
```

I've tried several changes: Modifying the supersized.css don't fix anything and probably the error is inside the supersized.3.2.7.js file but i don't have a clue of what to modify in it. Maybe the error is the style of the img but i don't know where to modify it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your css in question.

Comment: Why exactly do you need the supersized plugin? You seem to be setting the background image on the body tag anyway (which is what you're seeing on the homepage), it's only the supersized version that is getting stretched out of shape...

Comment: If you are wanting to use that image as a background image why not use it in a `background` css style, instead of trying to use an absolute positioned image element

Comment: @Joe Czucha i can't delete it because it's a part of theme i am using.

Comment: @Patrick Evans Using a background-size: 100% 100% didn't work.

Comment: Can you just put 

`#supersized { display:none; }` in your CSS?

Comment: it wont work till you use your image in a background style (ie `background:url(intro-bg1.jpg)` )

Comment: @Joe Czucha Yeah! It works. Thank you so much for the help guys :D How can i give you a point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be including a background image in two places: firstly on the `<body` tag and again in a supersized element (which looks like it's being added by a script).

If you can't turn off the script, just hide it using:

```
#supersized { display:none; }
```

and it will fall back to the body background.